# What is the purpose of using Open() and Close() Connection in ADO.NET. Means, CLR have GC functionality to remove the unused objects automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

CLR is using the GC functionality to remove the unused objects of the application automatically. At the time of working in ADO.NET, we are using the Open() and Close() method to make connection to SQL Server Database.
So, why we need Open() and Close() Connection mannually?

Comment: You should never rely on the garbage collector to clean up expensive resources, as you have no control over the point in time when the GC will choose to dispose of them.

Comment: Using `Using` will help you forgetting 'close`

Answer (score 0):

You can find details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> if the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore,
>   you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose.
>   Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent. If the connection
>   pooling value Pooling is set to true or yes, the underlying connection
>   is returned back to the connection pool. On the other hand, if Pooling
>   is set to false or no, the underlying connection to the server is
>   closed.